# How does this class work? (Related to Quantopian, Python and Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

From here: https://www.quantopian.com/posts/wsj-example-algorithm

```
class Reversion(CustomFactor):
    """
    Here we define a basic mean reversion factor using a CustomFactor. We
    take a ratio of the last close price to the average price over the
    last 60 days. A high ratio indicates a high price relative to the mean
    and a low ratio indicates a low price relative to the mean.
    """
    inputs = [USEquityPricing.close]
    window_length = 60   

    def compute(self, today, assets, out, prices):
        out[:] = -prices[-1] / np.mean(prices, axis=0)
```

`Reversion()` seems to return a `pandas.DataFrame`, and I have absolutely no idea why.
For one thing, where is `inputs` and `window_length` used?
 And what exactly is `out[:]`?

Is this specific behavior related to Quantopian in particular or Python/Pandas?

Comment: https://www.quantopian.com/help#quantopian_pipeline_CustomFactor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- `Reversion()` doesn't return a DataFrame, it returns an instance of the
  `Reversion` class, which you can think of as a **formula** for performing a
  trailing window computation. You can run that formula over a particular time
  period using either `quantopian.algorithm.pipeline_output` or
  `quantopian.research.run_pipeline`, depending on whether you're writing a
  trading algorithm or doing offline research in a notebook.
- The `compute` method is what defines the "formula" computed by a `Reversion`
  instance. It calculates a reduction over a 2D numpy array of prices, where
  each row of the array corresponds to a day and each column of the array
  corresponds to a stock. The result of that computation is a 1D array
  containing a value for each stock, which is copied into `out`. `out` is also
  a numpy array. The syntax `out[:] = <expression>` says "copy the values from
  `<expression>` into `out`".

  `compute` writes its result directly into an output array instead of simply
  returning because doing so allows the `CustomFactor` base class to ensure
  that the output has the correct shape and dtype, which can be nontrivial for
  more complex cases.

  Having a function "return" by overwriting an input is unusual and generally
  non-idiomatic Python. I wouldn't recommend implementing a similar API unless
  you're very sure that there isn't a better solution.
- All of the code in the linked example is open source and can be found in
  [Zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline), the framework on top of
  which Quantopian is built. If you're interested in the implementation, the
  following files are good places to start:

  - `zipline/pipeline/engine.py`
  - `zipline/pipeline/term.py`
  - `zipline/pipeline/graph.py`
  - `zipline/pipeline/pipeline.py`
  - `zipline/pipeline/factors/factor.py`
- You can also find a detailed tutorial on the Pipeline API
  [here](https://www.quantopian.com/tutorials/pipeline#lesson1).

---

I think there are two kinds of answers to your question:

1. How does the `Reversion` class fit into the larger framework of a
   Zipline/Quantopian algorithm? In other words, "how is the `Reversion` class
   **used**"?
2. What are the expected inputs to `Reversion.compute()` and what computation
   does it perform on those inputs? In other words, "What, concretely, does the
   `Reversion.compute()` method **do**?

It's easier to answer (2) with some context from (1).

### How is the `Reversion` class **used**?

`Reversion` is a subclass of `CustomFactor`, which is part of Zipline's
**Pipeline API**. The primary purpose of the Pipeline API is to make it easy
for users to perform a certain special kind of computation efficiently over
many sources of data. That special kind of computation is a **cross-sectional
trailing-window** computation, which has the form:

Every day, for some set of data sources, fetch the last N days of data for all
known assets and apply a reduction function to produce a single value per
asset.

A very simple cross-sectional trailing-window computation would be something
like "close-to-close daily returns", which has the form:

Every day, fetch the last two days' of close prices and, for each asset,
calculate the percent change between the asset's previous day close price and
its current current close price.

To describe a cross-sectional trailing-window computation, we need at least
three pieces of information:

1. On what kinds of data (e.g. price, volume, market cap) does the computation
   operate?
2. On how long of a trailing window of data (e.g. 1 day, 20 days, 100 days)
   does the computation operate?
3. What reduction function does the computation perform over the data described
   by (1) and (2)?

The `CustomFactor` class defines an API for consolidating these three pieces of
information into a single object.

- The `inputs` attribute describes the set of inputs needed to perform a
  computation. In the snippet from the question, the only input is
  `USEquityPricing.close`, which says that we just need trailing daily close
  prices. In general, however, we can ask for any number of inputs. For
  example, to compute VWAP (Volume-Weighted Average Price), we would use
  something like `inputs = [USEquityPricing.close, USEquityPricing.volume]` to
  say that we want trailing close prices and trailing daily volumes.
- The `window_length` attribute describes the number of days of trailing data
  required to perform a computation. In the snippet above we're requesting 60
  days of trailing close prices.
- The `compute` method describes the trailing-window computation to be
  performed. In the section below, I've outlined exactly how `compute` performs
  its computation. For now, it's enough to know that `compute` is essentially a
  reduction function from some number of 2-dimensional arrays to a single
  1-dimensional array.

You might notice that we haven't defined an actual set of dates on which we
might want to compute a `Reversion` factor. This is by design, since we'd like
to be able to use the same `Reversion` instance to perform calculations at
different points in time.

Quantopian defines two APIs for computing expressions like `Reversion`: an
"online" mode designed for use in actual trading algorithms, and a "batch" mode
designed for use in research and development. In both APIs, we first construct
a `Pipeline` object that holds all the computations we want to perform.  We
then feed our pipeline object into a function that actually performs the
computations we're interested in.

In the batch API, we call `run_pipeline` passing our pipeline, a start date,
and an end date. A simple research notebook computing a custom factor might
look like this:

```
from quantopian.pipeline import Pipeline, CustomFactor
from quantopian.research import run_pipeline

class Reversion(CustomFactor):
    # Code from snippet above.

reversion = Reversion()
pipeline = Pipeline({'reversion': reversion})
result = run_pipeline(pipeline, start_date='2014-01-02', end_date='2015-01-02')
do_stuff_with(result)
```

In a trading algorithm, we're generally interested in the most recently
computed values from our pipeline, so there's a slightly different API: we
"attach" a pipeline to our algorithm on startup, and we request the latest
output from the pipeline at the start of each day. A simple trading algorithm
using `Reversion` might look something like this:

```
import quantopian.algorithm as algo
from quantopian.pipeline import Pipeline, CustomFactor


class Reversion(CustomFactor):
    # Code from snippet above.

def initialize(context):
    reversion = Reversion()
    pipeline = Pipeline({'reversion': reversion})
    algo.attach_pipeline(pipeline, name='my_pipe')

def before_trading_start(context, data):
    result = algo.pipeline_output(name='my_pipe')
    do_stuff_with(result)
```

The most important thing to understand about the two examples above is that
**simply constructing an instance of `Reversion` doesn't perform any
computation**. In particular, the line:

```
reversion = Reversion()
```

doesn't fetch any data or call the `compute` method. It simply creates an
instance of the `Reversion` class, which knows that it needs 60 days of close
prices each day to run its `compute` function. Similarly,
`USEquityPricing.close` isn't a DataFrame or a numpy array or anything like
that: it's just a sentinel value that describes what kind of data `Reversion`
needs as an input.

One way to think about this is by an analogy to mathematics. An instance of
`Reversion` is like a **formula for performing a calculation**, and
`USEquityPricing.close` is like a **variable in that formula**.

Simply writing down the formula doesn't produce any values; it just gives us a
way to say "here's how to compute a result if you plug in values for all of
these variables".

We get a concrete result by actually plugging in values for our variables,
which happens when we call `run_pipeline` or `pipeline_output`.

### So what, concretely, does `Reversion.compute()` do?

Both `run_pipeline` and `pipeline_output` ultimately boil down to calls to
`PipelineEngine.run_pipeline`, which is where actual computation happens.

To continue the analogy from above, if `reversion` is a formula, and
`USEquityPricing.close` is a variable in that formula, then `PipelineEngine` is
the grade school student whose homework assignment is to look up the value of
the variable and plug it into the formula.

When we call `PipelineEngine.run_pipeline(pipeline, start_date, end_date)`, the
engine iterates through our requested expressions, loads the inputs for those
expressions, and then calls each expression's `compute` method once per trading
day between `start_date` and `end_date` with appropriate slices of the loaded
input data.

Concretely, the engine expects that each expression has a `compute` method with
a signature like:

```
def compute(self, today, assets, out, input1, input2, ..., inputN):
```

The first four arguments are always the same:

- `self` is the `CustomFactor` instance in question (e.g. `reversion` in the
  snippets above). This is how methods work in Python in general.
- `today` is a pandas Timestamp representing the day on which `compute` is
  being called.
- `assets` is a 1-dimensional numpy array containing an integer for every
  tradeable asset on `today`.
- `out` is a 1-dimensional numpy array of the same shape as `assets`. The
  contract of `compute` is that it should write the result of its computation
  into `out`.

The remaining parameters are 2-D numpy arrays with shape `(window_length, len(assets))`.
Each of these parameters corresponds to an entry in the expression's `inputs`
list. In the case of `Reversion`, we only have a single input,
`USEquityPricing.close`, so there's only one extra parameter, `prices`, which
contains a `60 x len(assets)` array containing 60 days of trailing close prices
for every asset that existed on `today`.

One unusual feature of `compute` is that it's expected to write its computed
results into `out`. Having functions "return" by mutating inputs is common in
low level languages like C or Fortran, but it's rare in Python and generally
considered non-idiomatic. `compute` writes its outputs into `out` partly for
performance reasons (we can avoid extra copying of large arrays in some cases),
and partly to make it so that `CustomFactor` implementors don't need to worry
about constructing output arrays with correct shapes and dtypes, which can be
tricky in more complex cases where a user has more than one return value.

Answer (score 0):

The way you presented it, that `compute` method might as well be static as its not using anything from within the `Reversion` class, unless whatever `out` is implicitly uses a predefined `CustomFactor` class when slicing/setting its elemenents. Also, since they don't share their source code we can only guess how exactly the `quantopian.pipeline.CustomFactor` class is implemented and used internally so you won't be getting a 100% correct answer, but we can split it into two parts and explain it using only Python natives.

The first is setting something to a sequence slice, which is what happens within the `compute()` method - that is a *special* sequence (a Pandas data frame most likely, but we'll stick to how it basically operates) that has its `__setslice__()` *magic* method overriden so that it doesn't produce the expected result  - the expected in this case being replacing each of the elements in `out` with a given sequence, e.g.:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(my_list)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

my_list[:] = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
print(my_list)  # [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

But in that example, the right hand side doesn't necessarily produce a same-sized sequence as `out` so it most likely does calculations with each of the `out` elements and updates them in the process. You can create such a list like:

```
class InflatingList(list):  # I recommend extending collections.MutableSequence instead

    def __setslice__(self, i, j, value):
        for x in range(i, min(len(self), j)):
            self[x] += value
```

So now when you use it it would appear, hmm, non-standard:

```
test_list = InflatingList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(test_list)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

test_list[:] = 5
print(test_list)  # [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

test_list[2:4] = -3
print(test_list)  # [6, 7, 5, 6, 10]
```

The second part purely depends on where else the `Reversion` class (or any other derivate of `CustomFactor`) is used - you don't have to explicitly use class properties for them to be useful to some other internal structure. Consider:

```
class Factor(object):

    scale = 1.0
    correction = 0.5

    def compute(self, out, inflate=1.0):
        out[:] = inflate

class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, factor, data):
        assert isinstance(factor, Factor), "`factor` must be an instance of `Factor`"
        self._factor = factor
        self._data = InflatingList(data)

    def read_state(self):
        return self._data[:]

    def update_state(self, inflate=1.0):
        self._factor.compute(self._data, self._factor.scale)
        self._data[:] = -self._factor.correction + inflate
```

So, while `Factor` doesn't directly use its scale/correction variables, some other class might. Here's what happens when you run it through its cycles:

```
test = SomeClass(Factor(), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(test.read_state())  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

test.update_state()
print(test.read_state())  # [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5]

test.update_state(2)
print(test.read_state())  # [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

But now you get the chance to define your own `Factor` that `SomeClass` uses, so:

```
class CustomFactor(Factor):

    scale = 2.0
    correction = -1

    def compute(self, out, inflate=1.0):
        out[:] = -inflate  # deflate instead of inflate
```

Can give you vastly different results for the same input data:

```
test = SomeClass(CustomFactor(), [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(test.read_state())  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

test.update_state()
print(test.read_state())  # [-7.5, -6.5, -5.5, -4.5, -3.5]

test.update_state(2)
print(test.read_state())  # [-15.0, -14.0, -13.0, -12.0, -11.0]
```

*[Opinion time]* I'd argue that this structure is badly designed and whenever you encounter a behavior that's not really expected, chances are that somebody was writing a solution in search of a problem that serves only to confuse the users and signal that the writer is very knowledgeable since he/she can bend the behavior of a system to their whims - in reality, the writer is most likely a douche who wastes everybody's valuable time so that he/she can pat him/herself on the back. Both Numpy and Pandas, while great libraries on their own, are guilty of that - they're even worse offenders because a lot of people get introduced to Python by using those libraries and then when they want to step out of the confines of those libraries they find them self wondering why `my_list[2, 5, 12]` doesn't work...